# Need help translating unity's old input manager to the new input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to using Unity and C# and I've been working on creating a movement system for a 2D platformer, and I've decided I want to switch to the new Unity Input System (because I can't find good information on the old one as all the search results I get are for the new one). I have it downloaded and installed and have watched a ton of videos but can't get any inputs to actually work in my game.

Here is the code which I need help translating:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class CharacterLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool playerIsAlive = true;
    Vector2 movementInput;
    bool jumpInput;
    bool doubleJumpInput;
    private float sprintTimer;
    private bool isSprinting;
    private int jumpsRemaining = 1;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool wallJumping = false;
    
    [Header("Collision")]
    public BoxCollider2D playerCollider;
    public LayerMask jumpableGround;

    [Header("Movement")]
    public Rigidbody2D characterBody;
    public float runSpeed = 7;
    public float maxSpeed = 10;
    public float jumpStrength = 11;

    [Header("Camera Tracking")]
    public CameraScript mainCamera;
    public float zoomSpeed;
    public float ZoomAmount;
    public float maxZoomAmount;

    [Header("Wall Jump System")]
    public Transform frontCheck;
    public float wallSlidingSpeed;
    public float checkRadius;
    public float xWallForce;
    public float yWallForce;
    public float wallJumpTime;
    bool isTouchingFront;
    bool wallSliding;

    [Header("Animation Settings")]
    public Animator animator;
    private string currentState;
    //Animation States
    const string PLAYER_IDLE = "Idle";
    const string PLAYER_RUN = "Running";
    const string PLAYER_SPRINT = "Sprinting";
    const string PLAYER_JUMP = "Jumping";
    const string PLAYER_WALLSLIDE = "Wallslide";

    [Header("Inputs")]
    public PlayerInput playerInput;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movementInput.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movementInput.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        isGrounded = Physics2D.BoxCast(playerCollider.bounds.center, playerCollider.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if (!isGrounded)
            {
                if (wallSliding)
                {
                    jumpsRemaining += -1;
                }else if (jumpsRemaining > 0)
                {
                    jumpInput = true;
                    doubleJumpInput = true;
                }

            }
            else if (isGrounded)
            {
                jumpInput = true;
            }
            // Wall jump
            if (!facingRight) 
            {
                if (movementInput.x > 0 && wallSliding == true)
                {
                    wallJumping = true;

                }
            }else if (facingRight)
            {
                if (movementInput.x < 0 && wallSliding == true)
                {
                    wallJumping = true;

                }
            }

        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Flip the character sprite's direction
        if (facingRight == false && movementInput.x > 0 && !wallSliding && (isGrounded || doubleJumpInput))
        {
            Flip();
        } else if (facingRight == true && movementInput.x < 0 && !wallSliding && (isGrounded || doubleJumpInput))
        {
            Flip();
        }
        // Jump
        if (jumpInput && playerIsAlive && wallSliding != true) 
        {
            Jump();
        }
        // Run
        if (movementInput.x != 0 && playerIsAlive && wallSliding == false)
        {
            Run();
            if (characterBody.velocity.x == maxSpeed)
            {
                mainCamera.xOffset = 6;
                //mainCamera.ZoomOut(maxZoomAmount, zoomSpeed);
            }else if (characterBody.velocity.x == -maxSpeed)
            {
                mainCamera.xOffset = -6;
            }
            else
            {
                if (movementInput.x > 0)
                {
                    mainCamera.xOffset = 4;
                }else if (movementInput.x < 0)
                {
                    mainCamera.xOffset = -4;
                }
            }
        }
        // Idle
        if (((movementInput.x == 0) && (movementInput.y == 0)) && playerIsAlive && wallSliding == false)
        {
            Idle();
            ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_IDLE);
        }
        // Reset sprint timer
        if (movementInput.x == 0)
        {
            sprintTimer = 0;
            mainCamera.xOffset = 0;
        }
        // Reset double jump
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            jumpsRemaining = 1;
        }
        // Detect wall collisions
        isTouchingFront = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(frontCheck.position, checkRadius, jumpableGround);
        if (isTouchingFront == true && !isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            wallSliding = true;
        }
        else
        {
            wallSliding = false;
        }
        if (wallSliding && !wallJumping)
        {
            WallSlide();
            ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_WALLSLIDE);
        }
        if (wallJumping == true)
        {
            ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_JUMP);
            Invoke("SetWallJumpingToFalse", wallJumpTime);
            characterBody.velocity = new Vector2(xWallForce * movementInput.x, yWallForce);
            Flip();
        }
        //Debug.Log(jumpsRemaining);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function sets the character's velocity in the Y axis to the value of `jumpStrength`,.
    /// It also preserves the character's current velocity along the Y axis.
    /// </summary>
    public void Jump()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Normal Jump");
        jumpsRemaining += -1;
        Vector2 velocity = characterBody.velocity;

        if ((velocity.x > 0 && movementInput.x > 0) || (velocity.x < 0 && movementInput.x < 0))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (movementInput.x > 0)
            {
                velocity.x = 7;
            }
            else if (movementInput.x < 0)
            {
                velocity.x = -7;
            }
        }
        velocity.y = jumpStrength;
        characterBody.velocity = velocity;

        jumpInput = false;
        if (doubleJumpInput == true)
        {
            doubleJumpInput = false;
        }
        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_JUMP);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function sets the character's velocity in the X axis to the value of `runSpeed`. 
    /// It also preserves the character's current velocity along the Y axis.
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {
        sprintTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector2 velocity = characterBody.velocity;
        if (sprintTimer > 2 && characterBody.velocity.x != 0)
        {
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                if (movementInput.x > 0)
                {
                    velocity.x = maxSpeed;
                    isSprinting = true;
                    ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_SPRINT);
                }
                else if (movementInput.x < 0)
                {
                    velocity.x = -maxSpeed;
                    isSprinting = true;
                    ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_SPRINT);
                }
            } else
            { 
                if (isSprinting == false)
                {
                    if (velocity.x > 0)
                    {
                        velocity.x = runSpeed;
                        isSprinting = false;
                        ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_RUN);
                    }
                    else if (velocity.x < 0)
                    {
                        velocity.x = -runSpeed;
                        isSprinting = false;
                        ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_RUN);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (movementInput.x > 0 && isGrounded)
            {
                velocity.x = runSpeed;
                isSprinting = false;
                ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_RUN);
            }
            else if (movementInput.x < 0 && isGrounded)
            {
                velocity.x = -runSpeed;
                isSprinting = false;
                ChangeAnimationState(PLAYER_RUN);
            }
        }
        characterBody.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public void Idle()
    {
        characterBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, characterBody.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 scaler = transform.localScale;
        scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = scaler;
    }

    private void WallSlide()
    {
        //Flip();
        characterBody.velocity = new Vector2(characterBody.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(characterBody.velocity.y, -wallSlidingSpeed, float.MaxValue));
    }

    private void ChangeAnimationState(string newState)
    {
        // Stop the same animation from interrupting itself
        if (currentState == newState) return;

        //Play the animation
        animator.Play(newState);

        // Reassign the current state to the new state
        currentState = newState;
    }

    private void SetWallJumpingToFalse()
    {
        wallJumping = false;
        jumpsRemaining = 1;
    }

    public void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext value)
    {
        Debug.Log("Jump");
    }

    public void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext value)
    {
        Vector2 inputMovement = value.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log("Jump");
    }
}
```

If anyone can help dumb this down for me I'd be eternally grateful. As you can see from the last two functions, I am trying to trigger unity events, assign the events to functions and write to the Debug.log so that I can see it's working. For instance currently, it should say "Jump" when I press the button I've mapped to "Jump" in the action map, but in reality it just triggers the old input manager stuff normally and the new stuff does nothing.

I have the PlayerInput class correctly attached to the CharacterLogic script in the inspector, and I believe everything is set up correctly with the events calling the right action map and function from my code (screenshot attached)

Help?

I have tried following every guide I could see on youtube and they were overly complicated and I couldn't see how I could translate how my old input system was working over to their methods.

Comment: I've solved it. I dont know what was wrong, but I deleted all the stuff relating to the new input system and just redid it from scratch and now it works sooo yeah

Comment: Glad you could solve this. If you know what went wrong please consider writing a complete answer in order to help future readers who have a similar question. If not please delete the question as it won´t help any other reader. Anyway voted to close as "not reproducible"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I figured out the actual issue. When you create a control scheme, you are given the "option" to add a requirement. It's not optional, if you don't add a requirement, it won't work. That should really be made a mandatory field.